# UserDefaults.didChangeNotification fires every time when view loaded

Tags: swift, cocoa, nsuserdefaults

In `class ViewController: NSViewController`

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func viewWillAppear() {
        super.viewWillAppear()

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(userDefaultsDidChange), name: UserDefaults.didChangeNotification, object: nil)
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear() {
        super.viewWillDisappear()

        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: UserDefaults.didChangeNotification, object: nil)
    }

    override var representedObject: Any? {
        didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }

    func userDefaultsDidChange() {
        print("user defaults did change.")
    }

}
```

There is no other code related to `UserDefaults`. When app starts, `UserDefaults.didChangeNotification` fires, when I touch the window that contains ViewController, `UserDefaults.didChangeNotification` fires again.

I don't know why this happens, as there is nothing changed at all.

------------------- This is a bug -------------------

I contact with Apple by TSI, people in Apple suggested me to file a bug on this. I did. [rdar://28928098](https://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=4949296721952768)

Comment: Did you set `frameAutosaveName` or "Autosave" of the window?

Comment: No, it is just a newly created project.

Comment: I tried your code and `userDefaultsDidChange` is fired once. What do you mean by "when I touch the window"?

Comment: I mean when you run the app, the notification fires. Then when you click the app's window, it fires again.